# What does 'def function=(param)' mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am sorry if this is a noob question, but I can't seem to find the answer neither in stackoverflow, nor anywhere else. The code is:

```
def full_name=(new_full_name)
  # stuff
end
```

When I define it in the console, and try to evoke it:

```
full_name       # nil
full_name       # [hangs, needs ^C]
full_name= arg  # works like normal function
full_name       # works again with no arguments, as if I passed the previous argument
```

So, **what is going on**?

Thanks.

Comment: Question: what does `def foo(param)` mean in Ruby?

Comment: 'define function with name foo that accepts one parameter with name param'. What is your point?

Comment: Okay, then: what does `def foo=(param)` mean in Ruby?

Comment: 'define a function with name foo= that accepts one parameter with name param'. However the function's behaviour has changed. My question is 'what happened?'

Answer (score 1):

A method ending with an `=` defines a setter. When defining a setter like that, ruby will always return the method argument regardless of the body definition when you call the setter.

You can then use `object.full_name= "Daniel"` which returns `=> "Daniel"`

---

Some other common appendices with your example:

The question mark, e.g. 
`has_full_name?`

is expected to return a boolean value if the object has a full_name

The exclamation mark, e.g. 
`revert_full_name!`

is expected to revert the full_name variable of the object

`revert_full_name`

in contrast is expected to return the reverted full_name variable but not to change it in the object

Comment: Don't forget about exclamation mark (!) which is often marks that the method will modify the object it's called on.

Comment: It is more than that. I am fairly certain it changes the behaviour of the function.

Comment: seems i was wrong and setters using = are special in that way as they always return their argument, regardless of the method body. edited that in the answer

Comment: No, setter methods return whatever is returned from them. However, assignments always evaluate to the assigned value, so, the return value is ignored. But it is still being returned, as you can easily see when you call the method without using assignment syntax (e.g. using `send`).

Comment: using a setter method isn't a real assignment but a method call. It's special that ruby returns the argument in that case and not the methods return. You can bypass that logic with send, but that doesn't change the special treatment of setter methods.

`def foo=(x); return "bar"; end`
does not assign anything but
`foo= "Hello"` will return Hello and not bar. send(:foo=, "hello") will return "bar" though.